# Google Directory API and PHP: Unauthorized client or scope in request

Tags: php, google-directory-api

I am working with the Google Directory API, a Service Account for oauth2, and PHP, run from the command line.

As a first step, I am just trying to retrieve a single user object. Here is the code:

```
require_once realpath(__DIR__ . '/../vendor/autoload.php');
session_start();
define('APPLICATION_NAME', 'Directory API PHP Quickstart');
define('SCOPES', implode(' ', 
array(Google_Service_Directory::ADMIN_DIRECTORY_USER_READONLY)));
putenv('GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=/path/to/XXXXXXXX.json');
$client = new Google_Client();
$client->useApplicationDefaultCredentials();
$client->addScope(SCOPES);
$client->setSubject('me@mydomain.com');
$httpClient = $client->authorize();
$response = 
$httpClient->get('https://www.googleapis.com/admin/directory/v1/users/me@mydomain.com');
print $response->getBody();
```

Here's the response I get:

```
Uncaught exception 'GuzzleHttp\Exception\ClientException' with message 'Client error: `POST https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v4/token` resulted in a `401 Unauthorized` response:
{
 "error": "unauthorized_client",
 "error_description": "Unauthorized client or scope in request."
}

' in /var/www/feeds/vendor/guzzlehttp/guzzle/src/Exception/RequestException.php:107
Stack trace: #0 /var/www/feeds/vendor/guzzlehttp/guzzle/src/Middleware.php(65): GuzzleHttp\Exception\RequestException::create(Object(GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Request), Object(GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Response))
#1 /var/www/feeds/vendor/guzzlehttp/promises/src/Promise.php(203): GuzzleHttp\Middleware::GuzzleHttp\{closure}(Object(GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Response))
#2 /var/www/feeds/vendor/guzzlehttp/promises/src/Promise.php(156): GuzzleHttp\Promise\Promise::callHandler(1, Object(GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Response), Array)
#3 /var/www/feeds/vendor/guzzlehttp/promises/src/TaskQueue.php(61): GuzzleHttp\Promise\Promise::GuzzleHttp\Promise\{closure}()
#4 /var/www/feeds/vendor/guzzlehttp/promis in /var/www/feeds/vendor/guzzlehttp/guzzle/src/Exception/RequestException.php on line 107
```

In the Admin Console > Security > Manage API client access, I have entered the Client ID with these API Scopes:

```
View and manage the provisioning of groups on your domain
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.group
View and manage the provisioning of users on your domain
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.user
Groups Settings
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/apps.groups.settings
```

The account I'm using for the subject ('me@mydomain.com') is a Super Admin on the domain. Domain-wide delegation is enabled for the service account.

What am I overlooking here? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Check if you have enabled the APIs in the Admin Console, also check if the service has beem enabled in your Google Project for Admin SDK.